# Monitor and alert when events have ended

Tags: google, html, web-development, security, cms

So I work for a private school, and we have only three I.T. Techs that take care of the entire campus/buildings, as well as the security systems and website. After trying to search google, I haven't come up with any ideas on what could possibly work, and only having a basic understanding of website administration does not help.

We are looking to see if there is a tool that will alert us when new content is added to the website by other members, and more importantly, rather than just any new content, content that contains dated information such as "Choir concert on October 30, 2014" so we are aware of when it needs to be taken off.

Is there a program like this that exists and would work? We would like to avoid having to make reminders in Google Calendar for something like this, since we don't know on a daily basis that a faculty member has posted up a new event. We are just trying to decrease the amount of outdated clutter on the website.

Hope this makes sense, and thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I understand this was put on hold but I find this a very interesting question (therefore the upvote). I don't think there's a tool available for this, but you should consider programming it yourself - I think it'd be fairly easy to make :)

Comment: There are tools that monitor systems for up-times, services, protocol availability, and so on that system admins use to monitor systems and alert them of failures. Amongst most of them is a way to monitor to see if a web page has changed and e-mail an alert. I used to use such a monitor for my web host business and it was an affordable option. This would allow you to monitor certain pages for changes at least and send you an e-mail so that you can check them. But it will not tell you of any outdated content.